# If I call a web service url in an android application, can a user discover the url that was used?

Tags: android

If it's using HTTPS?  A standard GET request to a particular URL.  If they still can, how can I obscure it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use http client method to send or fetch data than client can't get that url

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible to find out the IP address and the port. The path part of the URL can be hidden by using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

If an intelligent user has rooted their phone, anything goes. You can use Proguard to obscure your code to make it more difficult to reverse engineer.